# Como saber se o e-mail chegou ao Destinatário?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Estou construindo um sistema **(em PHP)** que necessita de aprovações, e a cada aprovação eu envio um email de confirmaçao para o usuário...

Estou usando o **phpMailler**, e ele me informa no final, que o servidor enviou o email..

***Mas eu queria saber (ter certeza) se o email chegou ao destinatário, tem como?***

Fiz várias pesquisas na internet mas até agora não encontrei nada... agradeço desde já ajuda de todos

Comment: Em princípio, o único jeito seria ter um _beacon_ embutido no email com ID único (uma imagem linkada num servidor seu). Mesmo assim não é garantido (pois a pessoa pode bloquear o acesso a imagens externas no email).

Comment: cc @Bacco Na verdade o protocolo de envio de emails oferece um mecanismo para receber uma resposta quando o email chega ao destinário (confirmação de entrega), bem como um mecanismo para receber uma confirmação de leitura. O destinatário, por sua vez, pode configurar seu client para não enviar estas confirmações (isto também está previsto no protocolo). Agora é você pesquisar se a biblioteca que você usa para enviar emails oferece uma propriedade para você setar e usufruir destes recursos.

Comment: Que, por sinal, tem um índice de eficiência muito menor que o _beacon_ atualmente. Mas é uma observação válida.

Comment: @Bacco Muitos clientes de e-mail, por padrão, também não exibem imagens *linkadas* até que o usuário confirme que quer fazê-lo.

Comment: Numa busca por "phpmailer delivery report" encontrei esta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1078300/1274092 (embora ela não use propriedades do phpMailler mas sim uma propriedade no header dos metadados do email). Esta busca retorna mais coisas que podem ser interessantes pra você.

Comment: @Tafarel_Brayan se for usar a confirmação por header, como sugarida pelo Caffé, lembre-se de criar um ID único pro endereço de resposta, para ter certeza que a confirmação foi da mensagem esperada. Por exemplo, email+idunico@example.com, assim você pode automatizar as confirmações. O _beacon_ já é menos complicado, pois é acessado diretamente no seu servidor, não precisando de um leitor de emails. Nada impede de usar as 2 técnicas e ainda por um link na mensagem final para que a pessoa possa clicar e confirmar manualmente o recebimento. PS: você pode usar o próprio logo do app como _beacon_.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma possível solução que pode te ajudar.

Supondo que você registre no banco de dados todos os envios que são realizados, numa tabela `envios` que contenha, por exemplo:

```
+--------+--------+
|idEnvio | status |
+--------+--------+
|     15 |      0 |
|     16 |      1 |
|     17 |      2 |
+--------+--------+
```

Onde 0 = E-mail aguardando envio, 1 = E-mail enviado, 2 = E-mail Lido

No seu servidor, crie uma página que receba o idEnvio para alterar no banco de dados, por exemplo:

alteraStatus.php

```
<?php

    $idEnvio = $_GET["idEnvio"];

    mysql_query("UPDATE envios SET status = 2 WHERE idEnvio = {$idEnvio}");

?>
```

No corpo do seu e-mail, insira uma imagem apontando para esta página, por exemplo:

```
<img src="http://seudominio.com.br/alteraStatus.php?idEnvio=16" class="imgEnvio"/>
```

De preferencia, deixe essa imagem com largura e altura zerada.

```
img.imgEnvio{width:0; height: 0; border: 0}
```

Assim, quando o destinatário abrir o e-mail fará uma requisição à sua página que irá alterar o status do envio.

Porém, se o cliente de e-mail do usuário estiver configurado para bloquear as imagens da mensagem essa solução não funcionará.